# Стоматолог и дантист

Tags: значение-слов

Скажите, пожалуйста, стоматолог и дантист - это одно и то же или разные вещи? Я слышала, что, мол, дантист не имеет высшего образования, а стоматолог имеет. Или это все-таки разные названия одной специальности?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Это разные вещи. Изначально дантистами были специалисты со средним образованием, удовлетворяющие потребность в большом количестве зубных врачей, а стоматологами являлись люди с высшим образованием по стоматологии.

Сейчас стало несколько иначе. Дантисты — это те, кто занимаются практической работой по лечению зубов, то есть и зубные врачи, и зубные техники (делающие протезы и так далее), и другой обслуживающий персонал. Стоматологи — это люди с высшим медицинским образованием по стоматологии.

Вывод. Не каждый дантист является стоматологом (например, зубной техник или зубной фельдшер суть не стоматологи) и не каждый стоматолог является дантистом (например, занимающийся научной деятельностью не является дантистом).

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее здесь: http://www.baby.ru/blogs/post/156663202-21913880/